# How to Resolved : cURL error (7): Couldn't connect to serverConnection Failure

Tags: php, curl

Sorry for duplicate question but i cannot resolved my issue ,
**Already check duplicate answers in stack overflow** but no luck.

```
  $data['fdate'] = 'XXXXXXXX';
  $data['tdate'] = 'XXXXXXXX';
  $data['key'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  $url = 'http://ip_address:8080/api/test/cm-test.php';
  $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
  // echo $url;
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json' ));

  // EXECUTE:
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
  }
  if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
  curl_close($curl);
  // print_r($result);
  $results = json_decode($result, true);
```

> cURL error (7): Couldn't connect to server

Comment: If configure firewall in the server then need to allow IP in the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an A2 hosting server problem (port 8080 problem)
Generated ticket and Resolved now.